# Temperature reading with a MAX6675 for for Higher temperatures

Tags: hardware

I am controlling the temperature in a Malt oven with a DS18b20 one wire sensor, but now need to read temps up to 400F which exceeds the limits of this sensor.  I am in Ecuador and have limited access to accessories but have managed to get a MAX6675 only to find it have been replaced.  Is there any way I can get a library for this device, and hopefully even some code to get it to read temperature on my RPI-3?  This would be great as I have just found a good supply of barley here, and am ready to really get cooking.

Comment: Checkout [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=145568) on raspberrypi.org.

Answer (score 1):

Also see http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_MAX6675_py which is an implementation using my pigpio library.

> A script to read the temperature from a MAX6675 connected to a K-type
>   thermocouple. The MAX6675 supports readings in the range 0 - 1023.75
>   C. Up to 4 readings may be made per second.